# When I try to validate the jsp form on keypress event, the alert box appears before entering any data into an input field

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

When I try to validate the jsp form on keypress event, the alert box appears before entering any data into an input field

```
<html>
<head>
<script text/javascript>
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
function checkTabPress(e) 
{
  for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  {
   if((inputs[i].value === undefined || inputs[i].value.length == 0) && (e.keyCode == 9))
    {
      alert("plz write");
      return false;
    }
  } 
    return true;
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    checkTabPress(e);
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter Your Name: <input onkeypress="checkTabPress('abc')" type='text' id="abc" placeholder=''><br>
Enter <input onkeypress="checkTabPress('xyz')" type='text' id="xyz" placeholder=''>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing your `onkeypress` event to `onkeydown`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `onkeypress` event to `onblur` (of the text inputs) and there is no need of addEventListener for `keypress`

**Updated DEMO JSFiddle URL** : https://jsfiddle.net/n6j7oy3b/3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: but the thing is when i press the first TAB key the cursor should move to the input field rather than showing the alert box.,as i m seeing the output on TAB event it shows alert window ......please help

Comment: What about the showing up the validation message then?, In other words when do you need to show the validation alert?

Comment: Thank you//.....see,when i tried to run the HTML page on browser,i wanted to move cursor onto input box on first TAB and after that when i press the TAB key and still the input field does not have any data then it should show that alert box....and same validation for other fields..

Comment: I have updated the DEMO Url to accordingly, and it works as per your requirement now, can you please check the updated JSFiddle URL given in my answer?